# Handle a string starting with "00" in SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-zeppelin

I use Hadoop/hive, and I'm having a problem with handling string data starting with "00".

Suppose that "00123" is stored as `string` in a Hadoop table.
My problem is that the following 2 queries do not show "00123" as it is. Instead, "123" is shown.

`select id from DB.TABLE where id="00123"
 select cast(id as string) from DB.TABLE where id="00123"`

I run the queries above on Zeppelin.
Can anyone help? Not sure the problem is due to Hadoop or Zeppelin.

Comment: Are you sure that the `id ` column is not stored as an integer?

Comment: I think the problem is Zeppelin. Strings columns don't remove leading zeros. Try it from the CLI or other JDBC Connector

Comment: I'm sure that the `id` column is stored as string. I will try other environments.
The problem doesn't occur on other databases, so I think the problem is due to the configuration of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in [ZEPPELIN-3701](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3701) (Missing first several '0' and losing digital accuracy in result table)

Wait for release 0.8.1.